# Pulling my hair out with mod_rewrite and MAMP

Tags: mod-rewrite, osx-snow-leopard, mamp

I'm using MAMP and I can't get mod_rewrites to work.

After lots of playing with numerous http.conf files and then finally looked at my php_info, there is no mod_rewrite exstension installed.

I opened up the php.ini files in Applications > MAMP > conf > php5.2 & php5.3 and looked at the exstensions and there was no mod_rewrite.so. All I can see is:

```
extension=imap.so
extension=yaz.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

I added it expecting a stroke of luck - but no joy!

Comment: Right i've found mod_rewrite is in the loaded modules which leads me back to square 1.

Comment: Uhm, did you forget RewriteEngine on ?

Comment: did you install mod_rewrite when you installed MAMP?  Check to make sure that you even included it with your installation, then try simply adding extension=mod_rewrite.so.  if that doesnt work, make sure you have rewrite engine on, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and hopefully this will solve it for you.

I added my site in my host file so instead of going through the locahost/..... It had its own url that I redirected to 127.0.0.1. i.e. my host file looked like this

> 127.0.0.1 mysite.local

I then set up a virtual host in MAMP. You will find the vhosts.conf file in /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache

My host file looks like this

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite-folder"
    ServerName mysite.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope that helps :D

Comment: I tried your virtual host suggestion and it didn't work. what does the second ServerName for, just naming? thanks

Comment: Note that with the second VirtualHost ("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite-folder") you'd have to add `AllowOverride All` inside a `<Directory>` for mod_rewrite to work.

Comment: I didn't need to do it in my case, I think you need this if you are rewriting the URL but correct me if I'm wrong. The first ServerName is a catch all localhost, you should keep that there. The second ServerName and any after should be site specific. Remember to restart MAMP and reload the host file when you make any changes.